# import css from public folder to any react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on integrating react package of content builder.

There are lots of files which needs to be keep in public folder and then add the references of css and js in index.html file

```
<link href="/assets/minimalist-blocks/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="/contentbuilder/lang/en.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/minimalist-blocks/content.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now the css is breaking all others application styles.

I am thinking to import css files in only the component where package is required, but since I am not aware of how to import from public folder,  I copied above two css files and put inside the src folder and imported. but it seems css files are using some other css fonts etc. so its not able to work...

Can anyone guide me how to import the css files from public folder to any component.

Thanks

Comment: Did you setup webpack config correctly? If not, please refer https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#pure-css-css-modules-and-postcss

Answer (score 2):

You can use  tag to include a css file in your React app.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css"  type = "text/css" />
```

Unfortunately, we can not import a css file from the public folder into a JavaScript file (React components).

To import a css file in React components you have to move your style.css file to the src folder and import the file in App.js like this

```
import './style.css';
```

Comment: as I said already tried this, but this css has internally linked with other files, so its not working

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `<link />` tag in side components' render functions:

```
return (
<>
    <link href="/assets/minimalist-blocks/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    ...
</>
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Write the css style in locally in your react app?